# How can I set up goroot in wsl2 goland

Tags: goland, wsl-2

I'm trying to set up goroot in wls2 Goland,but ut something went wrong:
"The selected directory is not a valid home for Go SDK"

[image]

What should I do

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, as of 2020.1.3, you cannot. See [the issue that tracks this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4377) and vote/watch it for updates.

Comment: A small update, there is a ticket to exactly support Go SDK in WSL: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10618

Answer (score 1):

**October 2021 update.**

Go SDK under WSL2 is supported in GoLand since 2021.3 (it reaches [Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/) at the moment). GoLand suggests selecting Go SDK on WSL2 mount if the location of the project is on WSL2 as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out my issue was having the go source code in c:\ drive. It must be in WSL2 mnt to work correctly. Tested on GoLand 2021.3.1